# Selecting specific class and add title to it with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a project where I retrieve large amounts of data from a csv which I have converted into an array containing over a hundred objects. Each object contains 15 data points as you can see below.

[image: Data]

What I'm doing below is select a specific class (.centrale-vak__key) and append a span with a class that matches item["Items in CHILDoc"] in the datafile. After that it adds the text in that same item["Items in CHILDoc"] to the span.

```js
$.each(data1, function (index, item) {
      if (item["Kwadrant in CHILDoc"] == "Centrale vak") {
            $(".centrale-vak__key").append("<span class='item-childoc_" + item["Items in CHILDoc"].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'') +"'>" + item["Items in CHILDoc"] + "</span>" + "<br>");
      }
})
```

What I would like to do is add a title to each created span (there are several "Centrale vak" items in the data file). For this I would like to use another data variable (data2). I have this snippet so far.

```js
        $.each(data2, function(index, item){
            if (item["Kwadrant in CHILDoc"] == "CHILDoc") {
                $(".item-childoc_ " + item["Items in CHILDoc"].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,''))
                    .attr("title", item["Items in CHILDoc"]);
            }
        })
```

For some reason the class selector is not working. Adding extra "" around it doesn't work either. Is there an easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
  $.each(data2, function(index, item){
        if (item["Kwadrant in CHILDoc"] == "CHILDoc") {
            $(".centrale-vak__key").find(".item-childoc_ " + item["Items in CHILDoc"].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0- 
            9]/g,'')).first().prop("title", item["Items in CHILDoc"]);
        }
    })
```

Comment: I think the explanation is that you are adding new items to the DOM, all the time that you are using jQuery you must refer to an existing element and then digging/finding to the created one, the same theory works with events (e.g onclick)

Comment: That explanation helps a lot. Makes sense now that you told me.

Comment: Is .first() required? It doesn't seem to change the outcome when I remove it.